# Subplots grid, legend outside, savefig does not work

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the same problem as this guy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971834/matplotlib-savefig-with-a-legend-outside-the-plot), so I want to put my legend outside the plot, but the savefig does not work. Additionally, I am working with the subplots environment. So let me phrase the problem here as general as possible:

```
 fig, axarr = plt.subplots(n,m)
 #... (plotting)...
 axarr[k,l].legend(loc=(X,Y)) # X and Y such that outside of plot
 plt.savefig("test.pdf")
```

By the way, for me the keyword 'bbox_inches' does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this it may work

```
lgd = axarr[k,l].legend(loc=(X,Y)) # X and Y such that outside of plot
plt.savefig("test.pdf", bbox_inches='tight', bbox_extra_artists=(lgd,))
```