# Rotating legend or adding patch to axis label in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I have an unusual use-case in matplotlib that I am trying to solve. I have a pair of axes created using `twinx()`. Each holds exactly one line object, with different styles. Rather than having a conventional legend, I must add a patch that represents each line to the y-label of each axis. Here is what I am trying to achieve:

[image: expected]

Ideally, the patch would be above the text, but that is a very minor detail compared to achieving the desired result.

I have attempted two approaches to this problem, both of which ended in failure. Perhaps a matplotlib guru can help:

**#1: Using displaced legends**

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.subplots(111)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
l1, = ax.plot((0, 1), (1, 0), linestyle='-', color='blue')
l2, = ax.plot((0, 1), (0, 1), linestyle='--', color='red')
leg1 = ax.legend([l1], ['Solid Blue Line'], bbox_to_anchor=(-0.102, 0., 0.102, 1.), frameon=False, mode='expand', loc=4)
leg2 = ax2.legend([l2], ['Dashed Red Line'], bbox_to_anchor=(1.102, 0., 0.102, 1.), frameon=False, mode='expand', loc=3)
```

As expected, this places the legends correctly, but does not rotate them. I am unable to carry out the rotation because apparently legends can not be rotated, despite being `Artist` extensions. E.g., `leg1.set_transform(leg1.get_transform() + Affine2D().rotate_deg(-90))` does nothing to change the angle of the legend:

[image: actual1]

**#2 Using a custom AnchoredOffsetBox**

In this approach, I attempted to construct a custom box containing a text and a patch. Unfortunately, the patch does not show up properly.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnchoredOffsetbox, TextArea, DrawingArea, HPacker
from matplotlib.transform import Affine2D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot([1, 2, 3], [0, 3, -1], color='g', linestyle='solid')
textArea = TextArea('This is an x-label')
drawArea = DrawingArea(1., 1.)
patch = Line2D((0, 1), (0, 1), color='g', linestyle='solid')
drawArea.add_artist(patch)
content = HPacker(children=[textArea, drawArea], align="center", pad=0, sep=5)
label = AnchoredOffsetbox(loc=10, child=content, pad=0, bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.1), bbox_transform=ax.transAxes, frameon=False)
ax.add_artist(label)
label.set_transform(label.get_transform() + Affine2D().rotate_deg(-90))
```

Again, the rotation does not work at all. Also, the patch is not scaled reasonably as it would be in a legend entry (notice the tiny green dot at the end of the label):

[image: actual2]

Is it possible to achieve something like the result I desire in MatPlotLib? I am willing to delve into the source code and possibly submit a PR if it helps any, but I have no clear idea of where to begin.

**UPDATE**

Looking at the source code, the `set_transform` methods of `matplotlib.offsetbox.TextArea` and `matplotlib.offsetbox.DrawingArea` are completely ignored. This means that my second attempt would be pointless even if I were to get the patch to draw correctly.

Comment: I placed an answer to another question that can solve your issue. Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47317114/3482418.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution which avoids the nightmare of trying to line up boxes outside of axes is to use latex labels with `textcolor`. The following code

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('ps')
from matplotlib import rc
rc('text',usetex=True)
rc('text.latex', preamble=r'\usepackage{color}')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
l1, = ax.plot((0, 1), (1, 0), linestyle='-', color='blue')
l2, = ax.plot((0, 1), (0, 1), linestyle='--', color='red')

ax.set_ylabel(r'\textcolor{blue}{--}' + r'$\;$ Solid Blue Line')
ax2.set_ylabel(r'\textcolor{red}{- -}' + r'$\;$ Dashed Red Line')

#may need to convert test.ps -trim test.png for picture
plt.savefig('test.ps')
```

results in the test file which looks like,

[image]

Latex lets you use \hline to design lines (or add `\n \usepackage{dashrule}` to the preamble), \circle etc for markers, colours of your choosing and you can control spaces with `\;`

UPDATE: few more examples of marker, colour and line styles,

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('ps')
from matplotlib import rc
rc('text',usetex=True)
latex_pream = matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.preamble']
latex_pream.append(r'\usepackage{color}')
latex_pream.append(r"\definecolor{lllgrey}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}")
latex_pream.append(r"\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0.56485968018118948, 0.7663975529283894, 0.86758939636894861}")
latex_pream.append(r"\newcommand*{\xlinethick}[1][1.0em]{\rule[0.4ex]{#1}{1.5pt}}")
latex_pream.append(r"\newcommand*{\xdashthick}[1][1.0em]{\rule[0.5ex]{2.5pt}{1.5pt} $\!$ \rule[0.5ex]{2.5pt}{1.5pt}}")

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.text(0.1,0.5,"Latex marker and line examples: \n $\;\;\;\;\;$ \{" 
          + r'\textcolor{blue}{$ - - \!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! \bullet \;$} ' + ',$\;\;$'
          + r'\textcolor{red}{$\bullet$} $\!\!\!\!\! \:\! \circ$' + ',$\;\;$'
          + r'\textcolor{lllgrey}{\xlinethick}' + ',$\;\;$'
          + r'\textcolor{lightblue}{\xdashthick}' + ' \}', fontsize=24)

#may need to convert test.ps -trim test.png for picture
plt.savefig('test.ps')
```

which results in

[image]

Comment: This goes a long way to solving my problem. For every use case I have come across, it works perfectly. Only potential problem is that it is a pain to re-implement all the marker features in latex should I ever use markers.

Comment: Also, is there any particular reason you wrote `r'\textcolor{red}{- -}' + r'$\;$ Dashed Red Line'` instead of `r'\textcolor{red}{- -}$\;$ Dashed Red Line'`?

Comment: it's great this worked for you. I had a bit of trouble with latex interpreter so split `$\;$` from the remaining string. You can get the simplest markers in latex, things like empty shapes with `"$\square,\circ,\triangle$"`. Lines with filled markers `-o-` can be implemented with something like `(\textcolor{blue}{$ - - \!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! \bullet \;$ })` and circles with outlines `\textcolor{red}{$\bullet$} \!\!\!\!\!\!\! $\circ$`. With hline in various dashed forms, I think that's all I've needed

Comment: I am thinking about writing a little package that does some fancy stuff to the preamble in rc and basically adds LaTeX "legends" to figure labels. Might submit it as a PR if it seems worthwhile.

Comment: Also, just wanted to point out that the preamble is normally a list, not a single string. You can just do `matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'].append(r'\usepackage{color}')`, etc.

Comment: The legend package sound like a good idea. Thank you for the tip on appending, I didn't know you could do this but lets you add anything, I've updated answer above with a few marker examples I have from various latex files.

Comment: What are the dollar signs for?

Comment: They denote inline equations in latex, you need them for around anything with a backslash e.g. `\bullet` `\circ` and for some reason the spacing (`;`, `\!` etc) doesn't work in the matplotlib latex interpreter without them.

Comment: Thanks. I've been using the `dashrule` package trying to get at least line styles represented in the general case. Ran into [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38062591/2988730), so it might take a bit more work than just coming up with the latex code to get this package working.

Comment: How much is `matplotlib.use('ps')` necessary here? I am having trouble getting colors to show up with my default backend.

Comment: I think so, yes. I got the latex color code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169052/partial-coloring-of-text-in-matplotlib which suggests this only works with the ps backend...

Comment: Bummer. I would really like this in interactive mode.