# Retrieving custom dashes in MatPlotLib

Tags: matplotlib

There are a whole slew of questions on how to set custom dashes in matplotlib lines using `Line2D.set_linestyle` and `Line2D.set_dashes`. However, I can not seem to find a way of retrieving the dash pattern after it has been set.

Here is an example of setting the dashes on the main site that I will refer to below: http://matplotlib.org/examples/lines_bars_and_markers/line_demo_dash_control.html. Code is copied here for clarity:

> ```
> """
> Demo of a simple plot with a custom dashed line.
>
> A Line object's ``set_dashes`` method allows you to specify dashes with
> a series of on/off lengths (in points).
> """
> import numpy as np
> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>
>
> x = np.linspace(0, 10)
> line, = plt.plot(x, np.sin(x), '--', linewidth=2)
>
> dashes = [10, 5, 100, 5]  # 10 points on, 5 off, 100 on, 5 off
> line.set_dashes(dashes)
>
> plt.show()
> ```

There is no `line.get_dashes` method. Calling `line.get_linestyle` returns `'--'`. How do I retrieve the actual dash pattern using MatPlotLib 1.5.1?

**UPDATE**

For those who care why I am asking: I am trying to create a simple converter from line-style to LaTeX using the `dashrule` package. The original inspiration comes from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38002700/2988730)/[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38008501/2988730). It would be nice if I could avoid using linestyle entirely and just get the dashes and linewidth directly.

I have learned to make markers with the [`tikz` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89823/108771), so it would be nice to eventually be able to add legend elements to axis labels. Given a bit more research and elbow-grease, I hope to combine everything into a PR to MatPlotLib.

**UPDATE #2**

There appears to be a "private" attribute of `Line2D`, `_dashSeq`, which contains the sequence I am looking for. However, the value of this attribute does not change if I set one of the preset styles: e.g.

```
>>> line.set_linestyle((0, (2, 5, 7, 3)))
>>> line.get_linestyle()  # This seems expected behavior for custom dash
'--'
>>> line._dashSeq         # This is what I want
(2, 5, 7, 3)
>>> line.set_linestyle('--')
>>> line.get_linestyle()  # This reflects reality now
'--'
>>> line._dashSeq         # This no longer does
(2, 5, 7, 3)
```

The problem is that I now can't tell the two styles (preset vs. custom) apart, so my question still holds.

Comment: The quotation was deliberate.

Comment: This is a bit of code that has been getting a bunch of thrashing recently (and ends up being coupled into the graphics contexts at draw time).

Comment: So there is no quick-n-dirty way to do this? Also, do you think there is any value to a PR for TeX-based legends that can be placed into labels, etc? I was thinking of either doing that or figuring out a way of getting all the elements of a legend to accept roatation so I can do this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38002700/2988730. Both appear to be non-trivial though.

Comment: @tcaswell. I am thinking of the following workaround for public API, let me know if it is sensible: `_dashSeq` to `None` when one of the preset line styles is set, and add a public `get_dashseq` method to retrieve the style. This way, `get_dashseq` in combination with `get_linestyle` will tell you everything you need about the line style.

Comment: This is probably needed + agressively updating the dash pattern as setting either linewidth or linestyle or the dash pattern (see https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/6592)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but as I was trying to solve a similar issue, I found that the protected attribute has since changed name (to `_unscaled_dash_pattern` and `_dash_pattern`), and exactly follows the expected logic. In other words, I think the issue just solved itself.

Notes:

- I'm using matplotlib 3.7.1.
- `_dash_pattern` gets scaled with the line_width. As far as I figured, this is to make sure dots are square.

Example:

```py
>>> line.set_linestyle((0, (2, 5, 7, 3)))
>>> line.get_linestyle()         # Expected behaviour for custom dash
'--'
>>> line._unscaled_dash_pattern  # This is what was needed
(0, (2, 5, 7, 3))
>>> line._dash_pattern           # This is the scaled version (lw=0.5)
(0.0, [1.0, 2.5, 3.5, 1.5])
>>> line.set_linestyle('--')
>>> line.get_linestyle()         # Still expected behaviour
'--'
>>> line._unscaled_dash_pattern  # Now contains updated dash pattern
(0.0, (3.7, 1.6))
```

Comment: It's never too late to deliver good news :) much appreciated