# How to savefig as show in matplotlib.pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend

I'm using `matplotlib.pyplot` to draw a bar chart with a legend, the figure saved by `plt.savefig()` is incomplete compared to `plt.show()`. To be more precise, the legend is out of the plot, the jpg file only have the leftside half of the legend.

My codes:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
plt.bar(x, y, label="a")
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.02, 1), loc="upper left")
plt.show()
fig.savefig("a.jpeg")
```

I looked through this answer [Matplotlib savefig with a legend outside the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971834/matplotlib-savefig-with-a-legend-outside-the-plot) but the chosen answer suggest to adjust the axis manually. I have many different figures so that may be inappropriate. Since it was posted years ago, I wonder whether any automatic method could be used to make the effect of `plt.savefig()` as `plt.show()`? I couldn't find any appropriate argument for that in `plt.savefig()`.

Thanks!

Comment: Does adding `bbox_inches='tight'` to savefig solve the problem?

Comment: Thanks! That help. But I don't quite understand the comment in the docs about `bbox_inches`. What's it for?

Comment: It is meant to simply removes white space, although I've found it solves problems with `savefig` where label text is cut off. A better solution may be `tight_layout`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774086/why-is-my-xlabel-cut-off-in-my-matplotlib-plot but again it seems strange you should need to in some cases.

Comment: Maybe I was doing wrong, but the `plt.tight_layout()` will cut off all the legend in the saved file, the `plg.gcf().tight_layout()` the same and the `plg.gca()` doesn't have the `tight_layout()`. I agree it's pretty weird to do additional setting to include an essential part of the figure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hope this will solve the problem.Add `bbox_inches='tight'` in the params which helps removing white spaces

```
 fig.savefig('a.jpeg', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
```